# How do I know if two things can see each other?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I know if there are two 'L's which can see each other vertically or horizontally? This is a grid-based question. This is the code I currently have, but it doesn't seem to be functioning.

```
def sight(board):
  lst = []
  for line in board:
    linelst = []
    for char in line.strip():
      linelst.append(char)
    lst.append(linelst)
  counter=-1
  count=-1
  
  for i in lst:
    
    count+=1
    counter = -1
    for item in i:
      counter+=1
      if item == 'L':
        numlstings = ['0','1','2','3','4']
        for inter in range(1, len(lst)):
          for inte in range(1,len(i)):
            try:
              
              
              
              if lst[count+inte][counter] == 'L' and count+inte > -1 and count+inte < len(lst) and count+inte > count:
                


                return 'unhappy'
              if lst[count-inte][counter] == 'L' and count-inte > -1 and count-inte < len(lst) and count-inte < count:
                
                
                return 'unhappy'
              if lst[count][counter+inter] == 'L' and counter+inter > -1 and counter+inter < len(i) and counter+inter<counter:
                
                return 'unhappy'
              if lst[count][counter-inter] == 'L' and counter-inter > -1 and counter-inter < len(i) and counter-inter>counter:
                
                return 'unhappy'

              if lst[count+inte][counter] == 'X' or lst[count+inte][counter] in numlstings:
                break;
              if lst[count-inte][counter] == 'X' or lst[count-inte][counter] in numlstings:
                break;
              if lst[count][counter+inter] == 'X' or lst[count][counter+inter] in numlstings:
                break;
              if lst[count][counter-inter] == 'X' or lst[count][counter-inter] in numlstings:
                break;
            except IndexError:
              break;
                
              
  return 'happy'
```

I want this code to return unhappy if it can see another 'L' in the same row or column, without the 'X' or the numbers intruding it. Otherwise, if it can't see an L it should return happy.

One such board is:

```
'......X.L.
.X..X...X.
L........L
X.....L...
....XX..X.
...LXX....
.X......L.
L.........
.......LXL
..LXL.....'.strip().split('\n')
```

This should return unhappy, but with my code it is returning happy.
There are also different boards which I have to test out.

Comment: Would something like `if 'X' in row and 'L' in row:` (or `if not 'X' in row:`) `return 'unhappy'` `else:` `return 'happy'` work for you?

Comment: @Party-with-Programming, no, because a row could be like ..XLX..L, which in this case it would not work as the two L's can't 'see' each other.